Table not displaying on HTML view in Flutterflow
I am trying to create a simple 3-column table using a HTML view widget. But it only displays "TABLE SECTION", as per screenshot.
I have tried stripping out some styling tags and using just a plain vanilla table, but it didn't work.


Getting the same thing here. It just shows a white rectangle with the words TABLE SECTION curiously. A smaller, simpler html renders just fine.

The official docs for the component doesn't mention anything but I can also verify that it does not seem to support tables.
It is using the flutter_html package for table rendering and it is supposed to have some support. However, in general this plugin renders the html with flutter components so you'll not get the same display as you would expect with a webview so perhaps you can experiment with a webview instead.
